# jquery that just waits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I normally set up my javascript code to have a function.  But due to the fact that the application generates most of the HTML and javascript calls from a VB6 application I would like to create a jQuery function that is more like a listener.  So for example if I have a td tag that has the class 'gridheader1' I would like the jQuery to wait for it to be clicked.

I'm assuming that I would use the bind...  But I'm getting javascript errors with it...  If you can offer suggestions on where my code is wrong that would be great.

```
$('.gridheader1').bind('click', function()
{
  alert('hi I got clicked');
});
```

Again this just has to sit out there on the main .js file.  It isn't attached to any functions.  Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: selector is wrong, should be .gridheader1

Comment: What errors are you getting?  When are you getting them?

Comment: You just described event handlers as though they're something totally obscure that's rarely used in web-applications... `:P`

Comment: @simoncereska - I'm sorry that was a typo on my part.  I have the '.' in my code.

Comment: @Jeff B - I'm getting $ is not defined...  However, I am using jQuery in functions above this code.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I know... :) I just haven't done them before...

Comment: You need to show more code then.  The code you pasted is fine... http://jsfiddle.net/fuuR5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// static tags
$(function(){ // DOM ready
   $('.gridheader1').click(function()
   {
     alert('gridheader1 clicked');
   });
});


// or if the tag is loaded via ajax use 'live'...
$(function(){ // DOM Ready
   $('.gridheader1').live('click', function()
   {
     alert('gridheader1 clicked');
   });
});


// or if you already have a function defined that you want to call, you can pass in the function instead of using an anonymous function.

function alertAboutStuff(){
  alert('gridheader1 clicked');
}

$(function(){
   $('.gridheader1').click(alertAboutStuff);
   // $('.gridheader1').live('click', alertAboutStuff); // for tags loaded via ajax
});
```

Comment: What happens if '.gridheader1' doesn't exist on the page yet?

Comment: Use the live method: http://api.jquery.com/live/ any time a .gridheader1 element is added the event handler will be attached to the tag

Comment: Done..  There was a time limit on when I could accept it as the answer.  That is why there was a delay!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

you want

```
$('.gridheader1').bind('click', function(){
  alert('hi I got clicked');
});
```

note the dot at the start of selector - it means class